# How to change the session language on login in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, login, login-screen, language-support

In older versions of Ubuntu it was possible to change the language (if language packs were installed) during the login. Therefore the login-window showed a drop-down menu with all installed languages.

Now I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 And I'm not able to find this drop-down menu. I only found the possibility to switch the keyboard layout.

Has this (useful) feature been removed? Do I need to install additional software to get the "language switch" back?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the default unity-greeter with lightdm-gtk-greeter. How you do that is described at

**System Settings -> Language Support -> Help -> Alternative language settings**